# A problem with the sextic Casimir of G₂

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I have a dimension problem caused by the sextic Casimir $S$ of $G_2$ (or $E_7$ etc., except maybe $B_3$).

- See [Macfarlane - Lie algebra and invariant tensor technology for g2](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0103021) for the "tensor technology".
- Let $R$ be the defining irrep (with dimension $d$, here $d=7$). As easily seen from the Clebsch–Gordan series, $\dim(R^{\bigotimes 6})=35$.
- $G_2$ has an antisymmetric quartic Casimir $V$. (It is not primitive, but can still be used for the following, instead of using ternary nodes. Diagram-wise this looks much clearer.)
  [image: tangles]
- With this Casimir plus a tensor for line crossings you can build exactly $40$ tangle diagrams with six open ends and without loops. (Diagrams with loops can always be reduced. Note that a crossing tensor "isn't there" and thus is no part of a loop!)
- $15$ of these have no $V$ involved, $15$ one and $10$ two. (I omitted the firstmost, they are obvious.)
  [image: bases]
- If you build linear combinations of these tensors adapted to the irreps of the full permutation symmetry group $S_6$, you get (in somewhat arbitrary notation for the irreps) $15=1_{+}+5_{+}'+10_{+},15=5_{-}+10_{-},10=5_{-}+5_{+}'$.
- Because of symmetry, any such "block" can only be zero as a whole.
- Specifically, the Jacobi relation kills one $5_{-}$ (a linear combination of the two occuring $5_{-}$ terms).
- So far, so good: We have $40-5=35$ independent basis tensors of $\dim(V^{\bigotimes 6})$, as above.
- But now the disaster happens. The (symmetric, i.e. $1_{+}$) sextic Casimir $S$ is primitive. If we could kill it, it would not be primitive. If we kill any other basis tensor, we must kill the whole symmetry block. Thus we could at most kill the one of $1_{+}$, but if such an equation would exist, we could easily trace off to get $d(d+2)(d+4)=0$ for the dimension of $R$.
- Thus we suddenly have $36$ independent basis tensors!

What is going on here?